# In WCF how to add two values, get the next value and subtract from the previous result?

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

hi i am new to WCF i want to create a confusing calculator for Unit Testing.

```
        public int Add(int n1, int n2)
    {
        int addedResult = n1 + n2;
        return addedResult;

    }
```

i know how to add two numbers and substract them. But how do you get the new number and subtract from addedResult?

Comment: The term `confusing calculator` sounds funny.You can ask for the 3rd number on that function. or you can return the result,get new number there and substract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do you get the new number and subtract from addedResult?

You have to expose another method with third parameter. Define that method in your Service interface and implement that in your service.

```
public int Add(int n1, int n2, int n3)
{
    int addedResult = (n1 + n2) - n3;
    return addedResult;
}
```

Remember to define that method in your interface.

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public int Add(int n1, int n2, int n3)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but i want to make something where one of them must call one of the others (composite service). How can we do that?